# Is it possible to create a data type getter for unions (in C language)?

Tags: c, types, unions

I have an array of pointers to unions:

```
typedef union element
{
  float f; 
  int i;
  long l;
  char c;
  char *s; 
} element;

typedef struct Array
{

  int capacity;
  int original_capacity;
  int count;
  element *elements;
} Array;
```

My code works, error free! I can append to the array or insert into it at an index, and soon I'll be able to do more. I can also print the entire array out, with an arr_print function:

```
int main(void){
  Array *arr = create_array(7);
  arr_print(arr);
  arr_append(arr, new_element_s("String 1"));
  arr_print(arr);

  arr_insert(arr, new_element_s("String2"), 0);
  arr_insert(arr, new_element_s("add"), 0);
  arr_print(arr);
}
```

Console:

```
Array count 3 and capacity 7
[add,String2,String 1]
```

The catch is I can only print the entire array out if the unions are of a single type and I want to be able to expand this capability.

Here is the arr_print function:

```
void arr_print(Array *arr)
{
  printf("Array count %d and capacity %d\n", arr->count, arr->capacity);
  printf("[");
  for (int i = 0; i < arr->count; i++) // 
  {
    printf("%s", arr->elements[i].s); // SEG FAULT IF MISMATCHED.

    if (i != arr->count - 1)
    {
      printf(",");
    }
  }
  printf("]\n");
}
```

printf causes a segfault error if the types are not matched.

For example if I add these lines:

```
  arr_insert(arr, new_element_c('a'), 1);
  arr_insert(arr, new_element_i(1), 1);
  arr_print(arr); // This breaks
```

I get a seg fault because a char or int is not a %s.

So, what I'm looking for is some way to tell the type of data the union contains (and then utilize a switch or something). In pseudocode I might do something like this

```
// typeof(arr->elements[i].data) == 'string' ? printf("%s", arr->elements[i].data)
// typeof(arr->elements[i].data) == 'int' ? printf("%d", arr->elements[i].data)
```

If there's not a native way, is there a function I could write that could parse the data/infer what it is, or is there some library that can do this? Or is this something you're just expected to know? I suppose I could make a struct wrapper for the union with a field that tells the type, but I don't want to if I don't have to.

Comment: *"I suppose I could make a struct wrapper for the union with a field that tells the type"* That's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @dbush is correct. This trick is commonly known as "tagged union".

Comment: did you check `sizeof` your union `element`

Comment: Thanks @dbush and thanks Ivan C for giving it a name!

Comment: @IrAM that does not work.